# get MIB file from a host

Tags: snmp

How can I get the MIB file from a remote managed HW?
The only thing that I know is the ip, port, community.

Can I use the net-snmp package? If yes, I'd like to have exact command.

Thank you!

Comment: SNMP protocol does not define an interface to store MIB documents on a device and query later. You can only get the MIB documents from the device vendor.

Answer (score 1):

To get information from the snmp tree (i.e. "snmpget"/"snmpwalk") `net-snmp` is the correct package. For downloading the MiB you will need package `snmp-mibs-downloader` ([non-free on Debian](https://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=sourcenames&keywords=snmp-mibs-downloader)).

See https://wiki.debian.org/SNMP

Some good examples to start with (Unfortunately in German, but understandable when google translated. And no, I am not familiar with these guys):

- [Read SNMP information via MIB Browser](https://translate.google.de/translate?sl=de&tl=en&u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.thomas-krenn.com%2Fde%2Fwiki%2FSNMP_Informationen_per_MIB_Browser_auslesen)
- [Query SNMP data with snmpget and snmpwalk](https://translate.google.de/translate?sl=de&tl=en&u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.thomas-krenn.com%2Fde%2Fwiki%2FAbfrage_von_SNMP-Daten_mit_snmpget_und_snmpwalk)

There are also lots of tools to manage/browse MiBs freely available.

Comment: I'm familiar with the MIB Browser, but didn't used it for the last few years and wasn't sure about its abilities. I'll check this